# Tomcat error log location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, jruby, war

I am working in Ubuntu, and I am looking in my tomcat/logs directory and there are only catalina.out files, but not catalina.err or something like that.

Is there a place where only errors are shown?  I am trying to debug why this ruby application is erroring out http://128.48.204.195:8080/blog and can't find the error trace.

Also, do ruby error traces get placed in a different spot from Java ones?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Unless you are using JRuby, the question doesn't make much sense. I therefor added the appropriate tag.

Comment: @Michael I am trying to use JRuby, but even if I didn't, Ruby can be run in a Tomcat container, right?  Why wouldn't the question not make sense?

Comment: No, you don't run plain old Ruby in a Tomcat. Tomcat's a servlet container and if you aren't sure what that means, have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet#Servlet_containers

Comment: As Michael Kohl said, if JRuby is not otherwise a requirement for you, if you just want to run a Ruby (on Rails) application you are better off running that directly from Apache (with the Phusion Passenger module) or using a Ruby-able webserver like Thin.

Answer (score 0):

catalina.out should also contain STDERR.  If you look in catalina.sh, you'll see the following line:

```
>> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

If you are running JRuby in a servlet container, the answer to this question likely relates more to something like JRuby-Rack configuration.

Answer (score -3):

ruby needs apache (not tomcat) so you need to look in your standard apache log (/var/log/apache or similar)

Comment: Sorry, but I was left under the impression you are running your ruby based app under Apache standard webserver -- otherwise why would you ask about tomcat? Tomcat is a container for *Java* based web apps not ruby-based! So I believe your question is somewhat misleading. Ruby doesn't require apache, I agree, but you will need a webserver (like apache though not necessary -- however, definitely not tomcat!) to run your ruby app.

Comment: unless he uses JRuby of course, in which case using Tomcat isn't out of the ordinary (I have done so myself). In that case it would be useful information to add though...

Comment: True -- in which case I would have expected this to appear in his question. Oh well, I guess I deserved the -2 for not asking for clarifications first.